# Dúvida JavaMail - Anexos vindo null

Tags: java, email, gmail, javamail, anexo

Possuo uma aplicação que faz download dos anexos que são enviados em um determinado e-mail e funciona perfeitamente.

Surgiu a necessidade de fazer a mesma coisa, em um outro e-mail. Os dois são gmail.

Porém, quando leio a caixa de entrada do segundo e-mail, todos anexos vem como nulo e isso não ta fazendo o menor sentido pra mim.

**Código:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        Email email = new Email();

        Store store = email.conectar(ConfigEmail.host, ConfigEmail.email, ConfigEmail.senha);

        Folder inbox = email.selecionaPasta(store);

        Message[] mensagens = email.mensagens(inbox);

        for (int i = 0; i < mensagens.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("Lendo: " + mensagens[i].getFrom()[0]);

            if(email.hasAttachments(mensagens[i])) {

                Multipart mp = (Multipart) mensagens[i].getContent();

                for (int j = 1; j <= mp.getCount() -1; j++) {

                    Part part = mp.getBodyPart(j);

                    // Exibe -1 para todos anexos
                    System.out.println(part.getSize());

                    // Exibe multipart/MIXED
                    System.out.println(part.getContentType());

                    // Exibe um endereco de memória
                    System.out.println(part.getContent());

                    //Exibe null
                    System.out.println(part.getFileName());
                }

            }
        }

        inbox.close(false);
        store.close();

    } catch (MessagingException | IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Estou tentando fazer o download de arquivos .XML

Não consigo entender o por que de no primeiro e-mail funcionar perfeitamente e no segundo, que é a mesma coisa, vir nulo.

Comment: Poderia separar a resposta (em um novo post) da pergunta?

Comment: dlosi, é legal você compartilhar a solução encontrada, mas pra ficar perfeito mesmo, seria legal você [edit] sua pergunta, recortando a solução, e colando no campo correto (o de respostas). Aí pode marcar sua própria resposta como aceita, assim o post fica marcado como solucionado.

Comment: Arrumei. Obrigado pelas dicas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUÇÂO:**

Por algum motivo, o e-mail que estou tentando ler, os anexos vem de uma forma diferente. Quando leio uma mensagem do inbox, pego o ContentType, se for multipart/MIXED, significa que possui anexos, então pego o conteúdo dessa mensagem e faço um for. Para cada iteração, eu estava esperando um anexo diferente, o q eu não estava acontecendo. Na verdade, estava vindo outro multipart/MIXED. Então fiz um método recursivo q resolvia este problema. Segue o código:

```
public void recursivo(Multipart mp) throws MessagingException, IOException {

    for (int i = 1; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {

        Part part = mp.getBodyPart(i);

        if (hasAttachments(part)) {

            Multipart multi = (Multipart) part.getContent();

            recursivo(multi);
        } else {

            if (part.getFileName().toUpperCase().contains(".XML")) {

                armazenaFile(part);
            }
        }
    }
}
```